# how can I navagate html found in a converted Json Object with powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm struggling with selecting the text I need from an internal website using invoke-webrequest
after I convert from JSON

**JSON**

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {"responseCode":0,"errorObj":null,"requestObj":null,"responseObj":{"SVG":null,"HeatMap":"<div id=\"hMap\">\r\n  <span style=\"position:absolute;left:0px;top:5px;height:2px;width:75px;\">Loop 1</span>\...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.1
                    Persistent-Auth: true
                    Content-Length: 643353
                    Cache-Control: private
                    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
                    Date: Sat, 05 Sep 2020 13:07:06 GMT
                    Se...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[X-AspNetMvc-Version, 5.1], [Persistent-Auth, true], [Content-Length, 643353], [Cache-Control, private]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
RawContentLength  : 643353
```

**Json  Object**

```
SVG           : 
HeatMap       : <div id="hMap">
                  <span style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:5px;height:2px;width:75px;">Loop 1</span>
                  <div id="jb8" rsv="8" title="Enc8-tt240(No disk issues found)" class="encDisk encDiskGood" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:25px;height:25px;width:75px;" dcList="10K " ud="0">
                    <div class="jbi">8</div>
                    <div class="hMapImgs">
                      <span class="icon ia icon-ci-check success" />
                      <span class="icon ib" />
                      <span class="icon ic" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="jb9" rsv="9" title="Encl9 - 12G EN-TT204 (No disk issues found)" class="enc8-tt240Disk enc8-tt240DiskGood" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:57px;height:25px;width:75px;" dcList="10K " ud="0">
                    <div class="jbi">9</div>
                    <div class="hMapImgs">
                      <span class="icon ia icon-ci-check success" />
                      <span class="icon ib" />
                      <span class="icon ic" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="jb10" rsv="10" title="Enc8-tt240losure 10 - 12G EN-TT204 (No disk issues found)" class="enc8-tt240Disk enc8-tt240DiskGood" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:89px;height:25px;width:75px;" dcList="10K " ud="0">
                    <div class="jbi">10</div>
                    <div class="hMapImgs">
                      <span class="icon ia icon-ci-check success" />
                      <span class="icon ib" />
                      <span class="icon ic" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="jb11" rsv="11" title="Enc8-tt240losure 11 - 12G EN-TT204 (No disk issues found)" class="enc8-tt240Disk enc8-tt240DiskGood" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:121px;height:25px;width:75px;" dcList="10K " ud="0">
                    <div class="jbi">11</div>
                    <div class="hMapImgs">
                      <span class="icon ia icon-ci-check success" />
                      <span class="icon ib" />
                      <span class="icon ic" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="jb12" rsv="12" title="Enc8-tt240losure 12 - 12G EN-TT204 (No disk issues found)" class="enc8-tt240Disk enc8-tt240DiskGood" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:153px;height:25px;width:75px;" dcList="10K " ud="0">
                    <div class="jbi">12</div>
                    <div class="hMapImgs">
                      <span class="icon ia icon-ci-check success" />
                      <span class="icon ib" />
                      <span class="icon ic" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="jb13" rsv="13" title="Enc8-tt240losure 13 - 12G EN-TT204 (No disk issues found)" class="enc8-tt240Disk enc8-tt240DiskGood" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:185px;height:25px;width:75px;" dcList="10K " ud="0">
                    <div class="jbi">13</div>
                    <div class="hMapImgs">
                      <span class="icon ia icon-ci-check success" />
                      <span class="icon ib" />
                      <span class="icon ic" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <span style="position:absolute;left:85px;top:5px;height:2px;width:75px;">Loop 2</span>
                  <div id="jb1" rsv="1" title="Enc8-tt240losure 1 - 12G EN-TT204 (No disk issues found)" class="enc8-tt240Disk enc8-tt240DiskGood" style="position:absolute;left:85px;top:25px;height:25px;width:75px;" dcList="RI-SSD " ud="0">
                    <div class="jbi">1</div>
                    <div class="hMapImgs">
                      <span class="icon ia icon-ci-check success" />
                      <span class="icon ib" />
                      <span class="icon ic" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <span style="position:absolute;left:170px;top:5px;height:2px;width:75px;">Loop 3</span>
                  <div id="jb2" rsv="2" title="Enc8-tt240losure 2 - 12G EN-TT204 (No disk issues found)" class="enc8-tt240Disk enc8-tt240DiskGood" style="position:absolute;left:170px;top:25px;height:25px;width:75px;" dcList="RI-SSD 10K " ud="0">
                    <div class="jbi">2</div>
                    <div class="hMapImgs">
                      <span class="icon ia icon-ci-check success" />
                      <span class="icon ib" />
                      <span class="icon ic" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="jb3" rsv="3" title="Enc8-tt240losure 3 - 12G EN-TT204 (No disk issues found)" class="enc8-tt240Disk enc8-tt240DiskGood" style="position:absolute;left:170px;top:57px;height:25px;width:75px;" dcList="10K " ud="0">
                    <div class="jbi">3</div>
                    <div class="hMapImgs">
                      <span class="icon ia icon-ci-check success" />
                      <span class="icon ib" />
                      <span class="icon ic" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="jb4" rsv="4" title="Enc8-tt240losure 4 - 12G EN-TT204 (No disk issues found)" class="enc8-tt240Disk enc8-tt240DiskGood" style="position:absolute;left:170px;top:89px;height:25px;width:75px;" dcList="10K " ud="0">
                    <div class="jbi">4</div>
                    <div class="hMapImgs">
                      <span class="icon ia icon-ci-check success" />
                      <span class="icon ib" />
                      <span class="icon ic" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="jb5" rsv="5" title="Enc8-tt240losure 5 - 12G EN-TT204 (No disk issues found)" class="enc8-tt240Disk enc8-tt240DiskGood" style="position:absolute;left:170px;top:121px;height:25px;width:75px;" dcList="10K " ud="0">
                    <div class="jbi">5</div>
                    <div class="hMapImgs">
                      <span class="icon ia icon-ci-check success" />
                      <span class="icon ib" />
                      <span class="icon ic" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="jb6" rsv="6" title="Enc8-tt240losure 6 - 12G EN-TT204 (No disk issues found)" class="enc8-tt240Disk enc8-tt240DiskGood" style="position:absolute;left:170px;top:153px;height:25px;width:75px;" dcList="10K " ud="0">
                    <div class="jbi">6</div>
                    <div class="hMapImgs">
                      <span class="icon ia icon-ci-check success" />
                      <span class="icon ib" />
                      <span class="icon ic" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="jb7" rsv="7" title="Enc8-tt240losure 7 - 12G EN-TT204 (No disk issues found)" class="enc8-tt240Disk enc8-tt240DiskGood" style="position:absolute;left:170px;top:185px;height:25px;width:75px;" dcList="10K " ud="0">
                    <div class="jbi">7</div>
                    <div class="hMapImgs">
                      <span class="icon ia icon-ci-check success" />
                      <span class="icon ib" />
                      <span class="icon ic" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
ContPanel     : <div class="navPanel" id="errorLeg">
                  <span>Status</span>
                  <div id="d1">
                    <span class="icon icon-14 icon-ci-ok-square-check success" id="errCheck" />
                    <span id="errListLink">No errors found</span>
                  </div>
                  <div id="uninitDisks" class="navPanelStatus">
                    <span class="statusIcon warning" id="uninitWarning" />
                    <span id="uninitMsg">32 uninitialized disks</span>
                    <span class="icon icon-inplace-help icon-ci-help-question-mark-circle" id="uninitMsgHelp" title="If all disks have not finished initializing, all disk space is not yet available for consumption" />
                  </div>
                  <div id="dataNote">
                    <div class="statusIcon warning" id="dataWarnIco" />
                    <a id="dataWarnLink">Data warning</a>
                  </div>
                </div><div class="navPanel" id="spareMode">
                  <span>Spare Mode</span>
                  <div id="rd1" class="navPanelStatus">
                    <span>Distributed Spare</span>
                  </div>
                </div><div class="navPanel" id="objStats">
                  <span>Disk Summary</span>
                  <div>Disks: 304</div>
                  <div>Enc8-tt240losures: 13</div>
                </div><div class="navPanel" id="contSum">
                  <span>Paths By Controller</span>
                  <div>
                    <table class="contsumTable">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Controller</th>
                          <th>0</th>
                          <th>1</th>
                          <th>2</th>
                          <th>2+</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr class="contRow">
                          <td>86900</td>
                          <td class="ccgood">0</td>
                          <td class="ccgood">0</td>
                          <td>304</td>
                          <td class="ccgood">0</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="contRow">
                          <td>86901</td>
                          <td class="ccgood">0</td>
                          <td class="ccgood">0</td>
                          <td>304</td>
                          <td class="ccgood">0</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div><div id="filterPanel" class="navPanel">
                  <span>Health Filter</span>
                  <div class="healthDiv">
                    <select id="healthFilter" class="select.small fieldValue rounded medium">
                      <option value="0">Off (No filter)</option>
                      <option value="Healthy">Healthy (304)</option>
                      <option value="Unhealthy" class="hCat">UnHealthy (0)</option>
                    </select>
                    <div>Unhealthy disks: 0</div>
                  </div>
                </div><div id="diskAttrPanel" class="navPanel">
                  <span>Class Filter</span>
                  <div class="diskAttrDiv">
                    <select id="classFilter" class="select.small fieldValue rounded medium">
                      <option value="0">Off (No filter)</option>
                      <option value="RI-SSD">RI-SSD (32)</option>
                      <option value="10K">10K (272)</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

when i select the .contPanal from Item

$item = $(ConvertFrom-Json $itm.Content).responseObj.ContPanel

it gives me Html below, I need to get to the 2nd last option value text

I tried a few variations of

$item.parsedHTML.getElementsByTagName('div') | where {$_.ClassName -eq 'dADIV'}

without any luck, any help or direction is appreciated

```
<div class="navPanel" id="errorLeg">
  

<span>Status</span>
  <div id="d1">
    <span class="icon icon-14 icon-ci-ok-square-check success" id="errCheck" />
    <span id="errListLink">No errors found</span>
  </div>
  <div id="isks" class="navPStatus">
    <span class="statusIcon warning" id="uninitWarning" />
    <span id="uninitM">32 uninitia</span>
    <span class="icon icon-inplace-help icon-ci-help-question-mark-circle" id="uninitMsgHelp" title="If all disks have not finished initializing, all disk space is not yet available for consumption" />
  </div>
  <div id="dataNote">
    <div class="statusIcon warning" id="dataWarnIco" />
    <a id="dataWarnLink">Data warning</a>
  </div>
</div><div class="navPanel" id="spareMode">
  <span>Spare Mode</span>
  <div id="rd1" class="navPanelStatus">
    <span>Distributed Spare</span>
  </div>
</div><div class="navPanel" id="objStats">
  <span>Disk Summ</span>
  <div>Disks: 304</div>
  <div>Enc: 13</div>
</div><div class="navPan" id="contSum">
  <span>Paths</span>
  <div>
    <table class="contsumTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Controller</th>
          <th>0</th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>2+</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="contRow">
          <td>86900</td>
          <td class="ccgood">0</td>
          <td class="ccgood">0</td>
          <td>304</td>
          <td class="ccgood">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="contRow">
          <td>86901</td>
          <td class="ccgood">0</td>
          <td class="ccgood">0</td>
          <td>304</td>
          <td class="ccgood">0</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div><div id="filterPanel" class="navPanel">
  <span>Health Filter</span>
  <div class="healthDiv">
    <select id="healthFilter" class="select.small fieldValue rounded medium">
      <option value="0">Off (No filter)</option>
      <option value="Healthy">Healthy (304)</option>
      <option value="Unhealthy" class="hC">althy (0)</option>
    </select>
    <div>: 0</div>
  </div>
</div><div id="diskAttrPanel" class="navPanel">
  <span>Class Filter</span>
  <div class="dADiv">
    <select id="classFilter" class="select.small fieldValue rounded medium">
      <option value="0">Off (No filter)</option>
      <option value="read">read(32)</option>
      <option value="under">under(272)</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short you want to get the value of the last option inside a div with `dADiv` class.

In order to do it, you can select all `options` inside that div, then get the last one :

```
// $item is your html
$elements = $item.parsedHTML.querySelectorAll('.dADiv option') # get all options inside dADiv
$elements[$elements.length - 1].value # get the value of the last option
```

- `querySelectorAll` means get all of items matching the given selector.
- `.dADiv` means an element with class `dADiv`
- `.dADiv option` means options inside of a div with `dADiv` class.

Comment: @elfranco91 if you want the also the text, use : `.text` instead. also if you want the one to the last (not last), use `$elements[$elements.length - 2]` instead.

Comment: thanks for looking at this, i added both lines of code as above and now get this error message, tried with .value and .text
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\user_name\Documents\PS_Scripts\Test\spin.ps1:24 char:1
+ $elements = $item.parsedHTML.querySelectorAll('.dADiv option')

Comment: @elfranco91 note that you also need: `$item = $(ConvertFrom-Json $itm.Content).responseObj.ContPanel` before this 2 lines. the error you get is when `$item.parsedHTML` is null. (just try to debug it, run the statemenets one by line and see what's happening and what causes the error.)

Comment: @elfranco91 here is what exactly works for me: open a new powershell, then execute: `$item = Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ya3ya6/stackplay_powershell/master/1.html` then execute the code in the answer. |||| first check if these 3 lines works for you. however in your original code, you need also `$item = $(ConvertFrom-Json $itm.Content).responseObj.ContPanel` (as you wrote in the question) to get the html from the json.

Comment: Thanks again, I invoked the github url  and I still get the same error

$item = Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ya3ya6/stackplay_powershell/master/1.html

$item

$item = $(ConvertFrom-Json $cst.Content).responseObj.ContPanel 


$elements = $item.parsedHTML.querySelectorAll('.dADiv option') 
$elements[$elements.length - 1].text

it fails on this line for me
$elements = $item.parsedHTML.querySelectorAll('.dADiv option') 

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Comment: @elfranco91 sorry if it was not clear: 1.for github one, remove the convert from json code. (it should be 3 lines of code, not 4.). 2. for your own case ("your original question) you need the json line.

Comment: Thanks again, i got it working now from the your github HTML, but for some reason, I still keep getting the same result when I try it from the HTML that  i get back from the JSON object

Comment: @elfranco91 no pfoblem, i don't know what to say because as you mentioned, the github html and your html is identical. However if you create a minimal github repo (or any reproducable code), then maybe i can debug it.

Comment: thanks again yaya, a friend pointed me in the right direction, the reason im getting the error is because what I get back from the JSON object is a string and not HTML

Comment: $elements = $cst.AllElements
$inner=($elements | ?{$_.class -like "*dADiv*"}).innerHTML
$innerupdated=$inner.Replace("'","").Replace("\","")
$patternWISSD = 'OPTION value="WI-SSD">(.*?)</OPTION>'
$WISSD=[regex]::Match($innerupdated, $patternWISSD).Groups[1].value

Comment: Used the above regex to search and it worked although takes a bit longer than I would expect, but at least its working

Comment: @elfranco91 No problem, glad you fixed it.